# JSON (Javascript) Steamcommunity Price

Tags: json, steam

Hi i would like to get the Price of a Steam Item unfortunately it doesn't work with the url.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=P90%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Factory%20New%29', function(fbResults) {

            document.write(fbResults.lowest_price);

        }); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? That URL spits back this JSON: `{"success":true,"lowest_price":"43,65&#8364; ","volume":"5","median_price":"42,57&#8364; "}`

Comment: [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Yes that's right, but if you open the html file nothing shows up... i tried it with a other site&json and it worked.. but not with this url